# How to draw rectangle with one side curved in html

Tags: css, html, svg

Is it possible to draw rectangle with top side curved in html?
Shape should be shown on bottom of the html page as it requires for footer.

[image]

Comment: What is the expected use for this shape? The easy option is generally just use an image with transparency, but it depends what you're using it for. (e.g. is it purely graphical, or do you need to put stuff in it?) I'd probably use an image for a footer shape.

Comment: you can use border-radius on previous element http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbgVZm

Comment: [Download Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/download/) and have a play. Your shape should present no problem at all to implement in an svg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:
this should show the first steps only :-)

```
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  left: 0;
  top: -50%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

you can play around with top(%) and the radius to fit your needs
hier is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tbm2jgbk/

Comment: thanks , is it possible to render left over part i.e  other than shape part  to transparent?
.wrapper:before background color to transparent without getting filled with .wrapper background color

Comment: sure but I background transparent won't change a lot instead of that use background-color:white (or whatever your background is) for the .wrapper:before (hier: https://jsfiddle.net/tbm2jgbk/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use an SVG that serves as a separator.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
main {
  flex: 3;
  background-color: purple;
  fill: purple;  /* Color svg separator will inherit from */
  position: relative;
}
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  fill: inherit;
}
footer {
  flex: 1;
  padding-top: 50px;  /* svg separator height */
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0 0 C 50 100 50 100 100 0 Z"></path>
  </svg>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```